# Id button from another window

Tags: c++, qt

I want to know the way that we can use an id button from a window to another.

For example I want to get a text from a window dialog that I create after clicking on ok button?

I've tried a signal that get the id button from a groupbutton, I've tried also to create a boolean variable that takes `true` when the ok button is clicked but nothing works.

```
bool Dialog2::getIdok()
{
    //qDebug() << "c'est id" << gb->id(b1) << "qui a été cliqué";
    if(gb->id(b1))
        return true; 
}
```

the arrow.cpp paint event which contains the drawtext that i want to change:

```
void Arrow::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem*, QWidget *)
{
    if (myStartItem->collidesWithItem(myEndItem))
        return;

    QPen myPen = pen();
    myPen.setColor(myColor);
    qreal arrowSize = 20;
    painter->setPen(myPen);
    painter->setBrush(myColor);
    QLineF centerLine(myStartItem->pos(), myEndItem->pos());
    QPolygonF endPolygon = myEndItem->polygon();
    QPointF p1 = endPolygon.first() + myEndItem->pos();
    QPointF p2;
    QPointF intersectPoint;
    QLineF polyLine;
    for (int i = 1; i < endPolygon.count(); ++i)
    {
        p2 = endPolygon.at(i) + myEndItem->pos();
        polyLine = QLineF(p1, p2);
        QLineF::IntersectType intersectType = polyLine.intersect(centerLine, &intersectPoint);
        if (intersectType == QLineF::BoundedIntersection)
            break;
        p1 = p2;
    }

    setLine(QLineF(intersectPoint, myStartItem->pos()));

    double angle = ::acos(line().dx() / line().length());
    if (line().dy() >= 0)
        angle = (Pi * 2) - angle;

    QPointF arrowP1 = line().p1() +
                      QPointF( sin( angle + Pi / 3 ) * arrowSize,
                               cos( angle + Pi / 3 ) * arrowSize );
    QPointF arrowP2 = line().p1() +
                      QPointF( sin( angle + Pi - Pi / 3 ) * arrowSize,
                               cos( angle + Pi - Pi / 3 ) * arrowSize);

    QPolygonF startPolygon = myStartItem->polygon();

    QPointF p3 = startPolygon.first() +
                 myStartItem->pos() -
                 QPointF( sin( angle + Pi / 2 ) * arrowSize,
                          cos( angle + Pi / 2 ) * arrowSize );

    arrowHead.clear();
    arrowHead << line().p1() << arrowP1 << arrowP2;
    painter->drawLine(line());
    painter->drawText(p3,m1);
    painter->drawText( arrowP2,m2);

    if (isSelected())
    {
        painter->setPen(QPen(myColor, 1, Qt::DashLine));
        QLineF myLine = line();
        myLine.translate(0, 4.0);
        painter->drawLine(myLine);
        myLine.translate(0,-8.0);
        painter->drawLine(myLine);
    }
}
```

And i have created a dialog class which contains an int variable that take 1 when i click on ok button,and in arrow class when i double clik the dialog shows up but when i click ok button nothing happen.Here is the doubleclickmouse event method:

```
void Arrow::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    if (mouseEvent->button() != Qt::LeftButton)
        return;

    mydiag = new Dialog2();
    mydiag->show();
    if(mydiag->cc==1)
    {
        m1 = mydiag->getvalue1();
        m2 = mydiag->getvalue2();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what is your aim. If you need only to get a text from a window dialog after clicking ok, you don't need any ids. Also please clarify if your dialogs are modal or not, how they are related to each other.

Comment: What i want to know is how to get a text from a combobox in a dialog class to use it in another window.

Comment: Can you put the text from combobox into class variable? Can you make a property for accessing to this variable from other window?

Answer (score 0):

When creating your custom dialog you may fill up that `QComboBox`, and when you closed your dialog you may read the data from that.

For exmaple you dialog header:

```
class YourDialog : public QDialog
{
// ...
    void setItems( const QStringList& aItems );
    QString item() const;
// ...
};
```

In your source file:

```
YourDialog::setItems( const QStringList& aItems )
{
    ui->ComboBox->addItems( aItems );
}

QString YourDialog::item() const
{
    return ui->ComboBox->currentText();
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
QStringList list;
list << "dog" << "pig";

YourDialog dialog;
dialog.setItems( list );

if ( dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted )
{
    const QString selectedItem = dialog.item();
}
```